Unable to open .png file in Fabric notebook
I am following the tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/assistant#supported-file-types
I created a notebook in Fabric.
I downloaded the packages using the following commands in a cell
%pip install openai
%pip install openai --upgrade
%pip install pillow

In the last step, when I run the code to open the sinewave.png file,
from PIL import Image

# Display the image in the default image viewer
image = Image.open("sinewave.png")
image.show()

I get the following error:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py:639, in _save(im, fp, filename)
    638 try:
--> 639     rawmode = RAWMODE[im.mode]
    640 except KeyError as e:

KeyError: 'RGBA'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:643, in Image._repr_image(self, image_format, **kwargs)
    642 try:
--> 643     self.save(b, image_format, **kwargs)
    644 except Exception as e:

File ~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:2413, in Image.save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2412 try:
-> 2413     save_handler(self, fp, filename)
   2414 except Exception:

File ~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py:642, in _save(im, fp, filename)
    641     msg = f"cannot write mode {im.mode} as JPEG"
--> 642     raise OSError(msg) from e
    644 info = im.encoderinfo

OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:344, in BaseFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    342     method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    343     if method is not None:
--> 344         return method()
    345     return None
    346 else:

File ~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:661, in Image._repr_jpeg_(self)
    656 def _repr_jpeg_(self):
    657     """iPython display hook support for JPEG format.
    658 
    659     :returns: JPEG version of the image as bytes
    660     """
--> 661     return self._repr_image("JPEG")

File ~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:646, in Image._repr_image(self, image_format, **kwargs)
    644 except Exception as e:
    645     msg = f"Could not save to {image_format} for display"
--> 646     raise ValueError(msg) from e
    647 return b.getvalue()

ValueError: Could not save to JPEG for display

